# Sencha touch 2 how to add a list into a container?

Tags: list, sencha-touch-2

Hi i'm new to Sencha touch and i have a problem. I looked up every answer i could find about my problem and tried all of them but i'm missing something.

I want to add a panel with some textfields and a list to my view. But my list is always in the background and i cant click it anymore.

Image:

[Image of the problem](http://postimg.org/image/ltal2ak2v/)

Here is the code:

```
Ext.define("NotesApp.view.TestPanel", {
extend: "Ext.Panel",
alias: "widget.testpanel",



config: {
    listeners: [{
        delegate: '#logOutButton',
        event: 'tap',
        fn: 'onLogOutButtonTap'
    }],
    layout: {
        type: 'fit',
    fullscreen: true
    }
},

initialize: function () {

    this.callParent(arguments);

    var logOutButton = {
            xtype: "button",
            text: 'Log Out',
            ui: 'action',
    }

    var form = Ext.create
    (
        'Ext.form.Panel', 
        {
            config:
            {
                layout: 'fit',
                height: '300px',
            },
            items: 
            [
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'name',
                    label: 'Name'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'emailfield',
                    name: 'email',
                    label: 'Email'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'passwordfield',
                    name: 'password',
                    label: 'Password'
                },
            ]
        }
    );


    var newButton = {
        xtype: "button",
        text: 'New',
        ui: 'action',
        handler: this.onNewButtonTap,
        scope: this
    };

    var notesList = {
            xtype: "noteslist",
        layout: 'fit',
            store: Ext.getStore("Notes"),
            listeners: {
                disclose: { fn: this.onNotesListDisclose, scope: this }
            }
        };

    var topToolbar = {
        xtype: "toolbar",
        title: 'My Notes',
        docked: "top",
        items: [logOutButton, {xtype: 'spacer'}, newButton]
        };

    var bottomToolbar =
    {
        xtype: "toolbar",
        docked: "bottom",
        layout:
        {
            type: 'hbox',
            pack: 'center'
        },
        items:
        [
            {
                xtype: "button",
                text: "testButton",
                width: "100"
            }
        ]
    }
        this.add([topToolbar,notesList, form, bottomToolbar]);
},
onNewButtonTap: function() {
    this.fireEvent("newNoteCommand", this);
},

onNotesListDisclose: function (list, record, target, index, evt, options) {
        console.log("editNoteCommand");
        this.fireEvent('editNoteCommand', this, record);
    },

onLogOutButtonTap: function () {
    this.fireEvent('signOutCommand')
}
});
```

The Controller:

```
Ext.define("NotesApp.controller.Notes", {

extend: "Ext.app.Controller",
config: {
    refs: {

        notesListContainer: "noteslistcontainer",
        noteEditor: {
            selector: 'noteeditor',
            xtype: 'noteeditor',
            autoCreate: true
            },

    },
    control: {
        notesListContainer: {

            newNoteCommand: "onNewNoteCommand",
            editNoteCommand: "onEditNoteCommand"
                },

        noteEditor: {
        saveNoteCommand: "onSaveNoteCommand",
        deleteNoteCommand: "onDeleteNoteCommand",
        backToHomeCommand: "onBackToHomeCommand"
                    }
            }
        },

    slideLeftTransition: { type: 'slide', direction: 'left' },
    slideRightTransition: { type: 'slide', direction: 'right' },

    getRandomInt: function (min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
},
activateNoteEditor: function (record) {

    var noteEditor = this.getNoteEditor();
    noteEditor.setRecord(record); // load() is deprecated.
    Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(noteEditor, this.slideLeftTransition);
},
activateNotesList: function () {
    Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(this.getNotesListContainer(), this.slideRightTransition);
},

        onNewNoteCommand: function() {
            var now = new Date();
            var noteId = (now.getTime()).toString() + (this.getRandomInt(0, 100)).toString();

            var newNote = Ext.create("NotesApp.model.Note",
        {
            id: noteId,
            dateCreated: now,
            title: "",
            narrative: ""   

        });

        this.activateNoteEditor(newNote);

        },
        onEditNoteCommand: function(list, record) {

            this.activateNoteEditor(record);


        },

        onDeleteNoteCommand: function() {
            var noteEditor = this.getNoteEditor();
            var currentNote = noteEditor.getRecord();
            var notesStore = Ext.getStore("Notes");

            notesStore.remove(currentNote);
            notesStore.sync();

            this.activateNotesList();
        },

        onBackToHomeCommand: function() {
            this.activateNotesList();
        },

        onSaveNoteCommand: function() {
            var noteEditor = this.getNoteEditor();
            var currentNote = noteEditor.getRecord();
            var newValues = noteEditor.getValues();

            currentNote.set("title", newValues.title);
            currentNote.set("narrative", newValues.narrative);

            var errors = currentNote.validate();

            if (!errors.isValid()) {
                     Ext.Msg.alert('Wait!', errors.getByField("title")[0].getMessage(), Ext.emptyFn);
                     currentNote.reject();
                     return;
                }

            var notesStore = Ext.getStore("Notes");

            if (null == notesStore.findRecord('id', currentNote.data.id)) {
                        notesStore.add(currentNote);
                    }

                    notesStore.sync();

                    notesStore.sort([{ property: 'dateCreated', direction: 'DESC'}]);
                    this.activateNotesList();
                },




        launch: function() {
            this.callParent(arguments);
                Ext.getStore("Notes").load();


        },
        init: function() {
            this.callParent(arguments);
        }

    });
```

And the list:

```
Ext.define("NotesApp.view.NotesList", {
extend: "Ext.dataview.List",
alias: "widget.noteslist",
config: 
{
    loadingText: "Loading Notes...",
    emptyText: "<div class=\"notes-list-empty-text\">No notes found.</div>",
    onItemDisclosure: true,
    grouped: true,
    itemTpl: "<div class=\"list-item-title\">{title}</div><div class=\"list-item-narrative\">{narrative}</div>",        
},


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell you how to fix the problem without the controller being present because i could not simulate the above problem. But here is my hunch based on the provided code that i tested, the problem might stem from the misuse of panels. As panels are the base for everything that is floating and modal, which is not what you want in this case(this is what Sencha touch in action states pg76). Also the noteslist has the layout fit but you aren't stating a height. The fit takes the height of its parent but we dont know what is the parent height as you are using the add. Lastly i suggest you take out everything from the initialize function and put it in the configs items  like i did below(now remember that the last one is a suggestion) Good luck :)

```
        config : {
            listeners : [ {
                delegate : '#logOutButton',
                event : 'tap',
                fn : 'onLogOutButtonTap'
            } ],
            items : [ {
                xtype : "toolbar",
                title : 'My Notes',
                docked : "top",
                items : [ {
                    xtype : "button",
                    text : 'Log Out',
                    ui : 'action',
                }, {
                    xtype : 'spacer'
                }, {
                    xtype : "button",
                    text : 'New',
                    ui : 'action',
                    handler : this.onNewButtonTap,
                    scope : this
                } ]
            }, {
                xtype : 'textfield',
                name : 'name',
                label : 'Name'
            }, {
                xtype : 'emailfield',
                name : 'email',
                label : 'Email'
            }, {
                xtype : 'passwordfield',
                name : 'password',
                label : 'Password'
            }, {
                xtype : "toolbar",
                docked : "bottom",
                layout : {
                    type : 'hbox',
                    pack : 'center'
                },
                items : [ {
                    xtype : "button",
                    text : "testButton",
                    width : "100"
                } ]
            }, {
                // xtype : "noteslist",
                layout : 'vbox',
                store : Ext.getStore("Notes"),
                listeners : {
                    disclose : {
                        fn : this.onNotesListDisclose,
                        scope : this
                    }
                }
            } ]
        }
```

FYI i just removed everything from the initialize and just left
     this.callParent(arguments);
but i dont think that you need that either because this will call on its parent constructor

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I added the controller to my main question. My problem is that i can't just config the items. This view is ust a reconstruction of a problem i'm having in an app for a company where i'm an internship. So ein obviously can't post that code here but the premade code im working with uses the push method instead of the add method. The code was working in Sencha 2.0. The problem is that i cant post the real code here but id would also help if someone could tell me what could have changed the push method since Sencha 2.0.

Comment: There is a little problem for me with your code. First i dont understand where you get the list if you comment out the xtype: noteslist and second i get an error that getStore is undefined.

Comment: I commented that xtype out because i didnt have the above noteslist definition. But you can add it back.

Comment: I am not sure what they could have changed in that push push. But an alternate solution would be to put all 3 textfields into a vbox or container layout and give the layout an absolute height hence forcing the content that will appear below to never to go underneath.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will the try the solution with the textfields in the vbox.

Comment: If the suggested solution works please dont forget to accept the answer.